# RegEx improvement recommendations

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a string like

> Some text and [A~Token] and more text and [not a token] and
>   [another~token]

I need to extract the "tokens" for later replacement. *The tokens are defined as two identifiers separated by a ~ and enclosed in [ ].* What I have been doing is using `$string -match "\[.*?~.*?\]"`, which works. And, as I understand it I am escaping both brackets, doing any character zero or more times and forced lazy, then the ~ and then the same any character sequence. So, my first improvement was to replace `.*?` with `.+?`, as I want 1 or more, not zero or more. Then I moved to `$string -match "\[[A-Za-z0-9]+~[A-Za-z0-9]+\]"`, which limits the two identifiers to alpha numerics, which is a big improvement.
So, first question is:
Is this last solution the best approach, or is there further improvements to be made?

Also, currently I only get a single token returned, so I am looping through the string, replacing tokens as they are found, and looping till there are no tokens. But, my understanding is that RegEx is greedy by default, and so I would have expected this last version to return two tokens, and I could loop through the dictionary rather than using a While loop.
So, second question is:
What am I doing wrong that I am only getting one match back? Or am I misunderstanding how greedy matching works?

EDIT:
to clarify, I am using $matches, as shown here, and still only getting a count of 1.

```
if ($string -match "\[[A-Za-z0-9]+~[A-Za-z0-9]+\]") {
    Write-Host "new2: $($matches.count)"
    foreach ($key in $matches.keys) {
        Write-Host "$($matches.$key)"
    }
}
```

Also, I can't really use a direct replace at the point of identifying the token, because there are a TON of potential replacements. I take the token, strip the square brackets, then split on the ~ to arrive at prefix and suffix values, which then identify a specific replacement value, which I can do with a dedicated -replace.
And one last clarification, the number of tokens is variable. It could just be one, it could be three or four. So my solution has to be pretty flexible.

Comment: We cannot help you until you define the token pattern requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all tokens and use the values you can use code like this:

```
$matces = Select-String  '\[([\w]+)~([\w]+)\]' -input $string -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches}
foreach($value in  $matces){
    $fullToken = $value.Value;
    $firstPart = $value.Groups[1].Value;
    $secondPart = $value.Groups[2].Value;
    echo "full token found: '$fullToken' first part: '$firstPart' second part: '$secondPart'";
}
```

Note in regex parts grouped with `()` this allows access to parts of you token.

In this loop you can find appropriate value that you want to insert instead of `fullToken` using `firstPart` and `secondPart`.

As for the `\[.*?~.*?\]` not working properly its because it tries to match and succeeds with text `[not a token] and [another~token]` as in this regex characters `][` are allowed in token parts.  `\[[^\]\[]*?~[^\]\[]*?\]` (`^` negates expression so it would read: all characters except `][`) would also be fine but its not that readable with all braces if `\w` is good enough you should us it.

Comment: interesting. Both a very different way to do a RegEx, and grouping. I'll need to dig into this a bit to fully understand it, but it's progress. Thanks. I do have a quick question to add. Anything here that won't work in PS2.0? I am limited to supporting old (ancient) PowerShell unfortunately.

Comment: @Gordon actually I do not know if this code is valid for 2.0 but if you have environment with it it would be easy to try executing.

Comment: No guarantie but started with `Powershell -Version 2`it works.

Comment: @Lotpings, thanks for the verification. I dug out my 2.0 test VM and verified also. Got some refactoring to do tonight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\w` to match a word character (letter, digit, underscore).
That results in the pattern `\[\w+~\w+\]`.
Now you can create a regex object with that pattern:

```
$rgx = [Regex]::new($pattern)
```

and replace all occurences of that pattern with the `Replace` operator:

```
$rgx.Replace($inputstring, $replacement)
```

Maybe it's also worth noting that regex has an `.Match` operator which returns the first occurence of the pattern and an `.Matches` operator which return all occurences of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example line

```
$String = "Some text and [A~Token] and more text and [not a token] and [another~token]"
```

This RegEx with capture groups

```
$RegEx = [RegEx]"\[(\w+~\w+)\][^\[]+\[[^\]]+\][^\[]+\[(\w+~\w+)\]"
if ($string -match $RegEX){
   "First token={0} Second token={1}" -f $matches[1],$matches[2]
}
```

returns:

```
First token=A~Token Second token=another~token
```

See the above RegEx explained on https://regex101.com/r/tp6b9e/1

The area between the two tokens is matched alternating with negated classes
for `[`/`]`  and the literal char `[`/`]`